# Userdefined datatypes vs Userdefined types vs User defined table types

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are three different types in sql server:

1. Userdefined datatypes
2. Userdefined types
3. User defined table types.

All these refer to a table structure which can be used by creating an instance...and seem to be the same, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

User Defined Types came before User Defined Data Types, which is essentially the same thing with the additional ability to combine multiple (different) data types into a single element / unit. They just renamed it. User Defined Table Types is just a subset of User Defined Types specific to table structure definitions.